# Prevent double notifications for an email

Tags: email

My Email app seems to notify me about new email from Gmail. However, I use Gmail app with my Gmail account too. In the end, I always got 2 notifications for 1 email.

How can I make the Email app to not notify me? (I prefer Gmail app)

Comment: What's your device model? When I setup my Nexus 5, it didn't automatically setup email account for me even though I use my Gmail account, so I think this "feature" comes from specific vendor.

Answer (score 3):

You **cannot uninstall** Email as it's a system app.
Either **disable** Gmail or Email from **Settings->Apps->All** .

Or **root** your phone and then **uninstall** it using apps like [System App Remover](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jumobile.manager.systemapp&hl=en)

If you can't do either of the above two, just somehow try to logout from either Gmail or Email so as to avoid double mails.
Or if you just don't want those notications alone, go to **App Info** of that app from **Settings->Apps->All** and untick the Notifications check box.

No other way other than these :)

Answer (score 3):

You can also simply disable email checking from one application.

For Email: **Settings-> [Account] -> Sync Frequency**, set to never.

Answer (score 0):

May be his option will help you out.

Remove your account from Email App.

To Remove Follow the Steps :

1. Open Settings
2. Choose Accounts Menu
3. Click on Email Option
4. Choose Remove Account

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to turn off notifications from the email application.

**Settings->Personalization->Manage Notifications**

This gives a list of applications that are permitted to give notifications.
Turn off Email, leaving Gmail on.